# Custom Collapsing Toolbar w/ WebView Very Jittery

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

#### Background

I have created a Composable that contains a TopAppBar and a WebView which recreates the enterAlways collapsing-toolbar behavior that Xml has.

The way it works is by applying `Modifier.offset {..}` to the composables. The offset is calculated whenever the WebView is scrolled. 
For example, if I'm at the top of the page, and I scroll towards the bottom of the page (swipe from bottom to top), the Y `offset` for both the WebView & TopAppBar decreases at the same time.

#### Problem

The problem is that it is very jittery whenever the TopAppBar is expanding or collapsing. I think this is because the `offset` for the WebView is changing **while** I'm still scrolling. In the previous example, the WebView moves up to take the place of the collapsing-toolbar, but my finger is still pressed on the screen while that happens, which may cause the device to interpret that as an upward scroll (swiping from top to bottom).

**Basic Outline of Code:**

```kotlin
Column {
    TopAppBar(
        Modifier.offset { IntOffset(0, state.toolbarOffsetHeightPx) },
        ...
    )

    WebView(
        Modifier.offset { IntOffset(0, state.toolbarOffsetHeightPx) },

        onWebPageScrolled = /** Update state.toolbarOffsetHeightPx */
        ...
    )
}
```

#### What I tried

One potential solution I thought of involves reading the scrolls (like I currently am) and also consuming them.

When the toolbar is collapsing or expanding, I realized that I should probably only adjust the `offset` during that time, and I should ensure that the WebView does not scroll its content.

Since the WebView's height is the screen height, when the TopAppBar is collapsing, the part of the WebView which was hidden at the bottom of the screen now comes into view, and to the user, the offset of the WebView changing would make it look like they are scrolling. Therefore, I should force the WebView to not scroll during this time.

--

The problem with this approach is that I'm getting the data about WebView scrolls from the `onScrollChangedListener`, so if I disable WebView scrolling while the TopAppBar is expanding or collapsing, then I also lose the ability to keep expanding/collapsing the TopAppBar...

Some solutions I came up for this are:

- Have a wrapper Composable around the WebView which can receive the scrolls.

I could not figure out how to implement this. It looks like there is a nestedScrolling Modifier which allows capturing scrolls, so I wrapped my WebView in a Box which had that Modifier, but even though I was consuming the scrolls in the `NestedScrollConnection` the WebView was still receiving scrolls normally..

- Use `onTouchListener` to receive scroll events rather than `onScrollListener`.

This gets a little complicated because `onTouchListener` is not only called for scrolls. I tried only running my TopAppBar/WebView offset logic if the `onTouchListener` was called for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, but the results were very strange.

I did manage to replicate the original expanding/collapsing w/ the TopAppBar & WebView, but rather than expanding/collapsing while I'm scrolling, the entire expanding/collapsing would complete before I even started dragging my finger - just pressing my finger and twisting it up or down completely expanded/collapsed the TopAppBar. 
The desired behavior is that the expanding/collapsing should happen linearly with the webpage scrolling, so this did not work.

I really appreciate any help. I've created a simple app on [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/GodSpeed010/Compose-Collapsing-Toolbar) if you would like to test the behavior.